# Do I Need to Run Git Init Multiple Times for Each Project I'm Working on?

Tags: git, terminal, command, init

I will be working on two different web apps over a period of time.  The projects are stored in the following manner:

Git Projects (main folder)

(sub directories)

- Project A
- Project B

Do I first need to navigate to the Project A folder, run `git init`, and then repeate the same process for the Project B folder?  Should I just run `git init` while in the Git Projects folder in terminal?

What is the best way to use the git init command in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Use [git init](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) for every individual git repository.

So, if you want Project A and Project B to exist in two separate repositories (which I recommend), then yes execute `git init` in each directory.  This, among other things, will give each project its own commit history.

Think of `git init` as creating an empty git repository within a directory, to which you can then `git add` any files you wish.  Thus, it makes sense that for each repository you create you'll have to execute `git init`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the man page, `git init` is a command that creates an empty repository, and thus needs to be executed for every new project that is currently not under the git system. So yes, navigate into each of the Project A directory and Project B directory and run `git init`.

You should **not** run `git init` while in the 'Git Projects' directory in the terminal, but this is more of a matter of following best-practices than it is a matter of incorrectness - doing so would basically tell git that you desire the 'Git Projects' folder to be a discrete project, and group all files within that project folder together. As you stated in your original question, Project A and Project B are different projects, and so should be stored as such.